# What is the use of lmaxcount argument in CreateSemaphore() API?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am Learning Windows OS, and I was writing the standard consumer producer problem. I am having a semaphore for the resource count and a Mutex for synchronization. I have passed the value of max count 50 in CreateSemaphore(), so it should not allow producer to create more then 50 resources. But when I am running the code it going far beyond that. Did I understand the use of max count argument incorrectly ?? 
I am also pasting the code. Please help me to shoot this problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI consumerThread(LPVOID args);
DWORD WINAPI producerThread(LPVOID args);

int shared;
HANDLE hMutex;
HANDLE hSemaphore;
HANDLE hConsumer;
HANDLE hProducer;
DWORD dwConsumerId,dwProducerId;

#define MAX_COUNT 50
#define MIN_COUNT 0
int main()
{
    if(!(hMutex=CreateMutex(NULL,0,NULL)))
    {
        puts("Error:: unable to create Mutex!!");
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }
    if(!(hSemaphore=CreateSemaphore(NULL,MIN_COUNT,MAX_COUNT,NULL)))
    {
        puts("Error:: unable to create Semaphore object!!");
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }
    if(!(hConsumer=CreateThread(NULL,0,consumerThread,NULL,0,&dwConsumerId)))
    {
        puts("Error:: unable to create consumer Thread!!");
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }
    if(!(hProducer=CreateThread(NULL,0,producerThread,NULL,0,&dwProducerId)))
    {
        puts("Error:: unable to create producer Thread!!");
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(hConsumer,INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(hProducer,INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hMutex);
    CloseHandle(hSemaphore);
    CloseHandle(hConsumer);
    CloseHandle(hProducer);
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI consumerThread(LPVOID args)
{

    while(1)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore,INFINITE);
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);
        shared--;
        printf("Consumer  = %d\n",shared);
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        //Sleep(1000);
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI producerThread(LPVOID args)
{
    if(!SetThreadPriority(hProducer,THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST))
    {
        printf("Error:: Unable to set the thread priority level!!\n");
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }
    while(1)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);
        shared++;
        printf("Producer =%d\n",shared);
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
            ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore,1,NULL);


    }
}
```

Comment: You are just using the semaphore wrong.  It only blocks when you call WFSO and reaches zero.  There is no "min count".  You must initialize it to MAX_COUNT and call WFSO in the producer.  And release in the consumer.  Watch out for deadlock.

Comment: i got your point, but then what is the use of lmaxcout parameter? why they have provided two arguments, initial value and max count ??  The way you are telling me to use it, i just need one argument, initialize it by some value and call the WFSO ??

Comment: There's no point as long as you don't check the return value of ReleaseSemaphore().  Which will tell you when your code has a bug and released too often.  Not something you'd ever want to skip.

Comment: "Why they have provided two arguments, initial value and max count ??" For the same reason `CreateEvent` has `bInitialState` parameter, and `CreateMutex` has `bInitialOwner` parameter.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik in CreateEvent bInitialState allow me to create a new object in signaled or not signaled state, in CreateMutex bInitalOwner allow the me to take the ownership of the mutex. So all these make sense. What is the use of lmaxcount, if its not blocking the thread which is incrementing it further this limit ?

Comment: @HansPassant Didn't get your point ?

Comment: "The maximum count for the semaphore object. This value must be greater than zero" this is written on MSDN doc for the lmaxcount argument. Now what I am suppose to get from it ?

Comment: Think of it this way. A semaphore, conceptually, controls the use of `lMaximumCount` shared resources. When a thread successfully completes a wait on the semaphore, it's granted a use of one resource; the "available resources" counter is decreased by one. `ReleaseSemaphore` returns one or more resources to the free pool; the counter is increased accordingly. `lInitialCount` parameter allows the creator of the semaphore to grab `lMaximumCount-lInitialCount` resources right from the start (just as `bInitalOwner` allows the creator of a mutex to own it right from the start).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You mean to say that if a thread will try to decrement the value of semaphore below it's lInitialCount it will get blocked ?

Comment: No, if a thread will try to decrement the value below zero it will get blocked. Let's try yet another way: `CreateSemaphore(NULL,10, 20, NULL)` creates a semaphore with the initial counter of 10. That counter cannot go below 0, or above 20. A thread that attempts to decrement it below 0, by means of `WaitForSingleObject` or similar, will block until another thread increments the counter. A `ReleaseSemaphore` call that attempts to raise the counter above 20 will fail.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  No, that is what I asked in this problem, that even a thread is raising the value more the 20(50 in my case), neither its getting failed nor its getting blocked. The API easily allow it to increment beyond lmaxcount .. :( !!

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary proof. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms685071.aspx) for `ReleaseSemaphore` says: "*lReleaseCount*: If the specified amount would cause the semaphore's count to exceed the maximum count that was specified when the semaphore was created, the count is not changed and the function returns FALSE." Are you saying you have an example that demonstrates otherwise? I can't help but notice that the code you show doesn't check the return value of `ReleaseSemaphore` - what makes you believe that the call succeeds?

Comment: ahh!! got your point. sorry for wasting your time sir. And thank you very much for being with me in such a silly mistake.

Comment: @Hans Passant  thank you also, now i realized your point what you were saying !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Question is answered in comments by @Hans Passant and @Igor Tandetnik. And the gist is that if you try to increment the value of semaphore beyond the value specified in lmaxcount argument the ReleaseSemaphore() API will fail instead of blocking the calling thread. So you should check it's return value as I didn't do that and fall into trouble. :)